# How to validate entered value is same as pre-defined value?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to verify that an email verification code entered by a user is same as one returned earlier by another technical profile. This journey step works as expected when the user enters the correct code but hangs when the user enters an incorrect code. What am I doing wrong. Here is the technical policy executed by my journey step:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="EnterEmailVerifyCode">
      <DisplayName>Email entry</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailVerificationCodeEntered" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailVerificationCodeEntered" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
         <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertEmailVerificationCodesAreEqual" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self-asserted technical profile must [invoke the claims transformation as a validation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile#use-a-validation-technical-profile).

Declare a claims transformation technical profile that invokes the claims transformation:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="ValidateEmailVerificationCodes">
  <DisplayName>Validate Email Verification Codes</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailVerificationCodeEntered" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailVerificationCodeGenerated" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailVerificationCodeEntered" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertEmailVerificationCodesAreEqual" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Then invoke this claims transformation technical profile from the self-asserted technical profile as a validation technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="EnterEmailVerifyCode">
  ...
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    ...
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">The verification code is invalid</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailVerificationCodeEntered" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailVerificationCodeEntered" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ValidateEmailVerificationCodes" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

**UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual** specifies the error message that is shown if the claims transformation raises errors.